# TinyMCE - onSetContent documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, code-documentation, tinymce-6

Does anyone have any idea how we can use onSetContent of tinyMCE react?? I want to use it in my project as there's some issue with the editor's dirty state. But I don't see any documentation in their official websites... Does anyone know?
Thanks.